# Умножение и побитовый сдвиг. Что быстрее?

Tags: c

Умножение и побитовый сдвиг. Что быстрее?

Comment: Чем вызван подобный вопрос?

Comment: просто прикинул что при побитовом сдвиге искомое число увеличивается или уменьшается в 2_в_степени_битов раз, вот и стало интересно как это вообще работает...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Двоичное умножение включает в себя операции сдвига и сложения, которые произодятся многократно. Поэтому, за исключением случая умножнения на число, являющееся степенью двойки, умножение всегда будет медленнее сдвига. Правда на современных процессорах вследствие разных эффектов (оптимизации, кэширования и т.п.) разницы может практически не быть.

Answer (score 1):

Если умножение кратно 2, то равны. Иначе, побитовый сдвиг будет быстрее.